# Deep Learning Keras Simple RNN for Time Series, predict multiple

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am quite new to Deep Learning and hence looked at how to solve time series problems with Keras. However, these were quite different.
Let me explain my problem in PYTHON:
 Attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9zFq.png) I have a data frame: rows represent each city of the US (rows=samples) and each column the time series between 1985-2018 displaying the avg temperature per year (columns=avg temp per year) - hence, the years of the time series is an individual feature column.

The task is now to predict the temperature for 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 for each city.

For this, I want to apply the Rolling Window technique.

1)Now, to apply a Simple RNN in Python Keras, how would I construct the input and output dimensions?
Does the X_train need to be X.shape=(cities, time_steps,features) or is it actually 4-dim: (number_of_batches,time_steps,features*cities)?

And especially, how do I construct the model to predict each year for each city?

I don't get this problem.
Thank you VERY MUCH for your assistance!

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please post your example data as text instead of an image

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to properly define your problem, i.e., inputs, outputs and features.
In regards to your first question, Keras 3d input shape is defined as (batch_size, timesteps, features), where batch_size is the number of observations the model sees before backpropagation (you will have to optimize this hyperparameter), timesteps is the length of a sequence in your data. In your case you can use 1. Features is the amount of features your are using. From the data image you showed, I assumed you are only using the temperature of the cities as features.

When you Transpose your data table, this becomes more intuitive. Hence, your input shape could be this Xshape = (10, 1, 6).

For your second question, I would advice you to follow one of the many awesome time series forecasting on [this website](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I thought that each year is a feature, so 33 features? What if I create a window size of 4, so taking 1985-1988 to predict 1989 and so on? And why 6 as feature size? I want to predict the temperature for each year after the window size for each city...

Comment: Reducing the size of the problem can help you understand the terminology. Take the time series of LA. Each time step is considered as an observation of temp in LA. In 1985 you sample 27. When you keep sampling temperature, you create a time series or sequence of your feature. You can consider a feature as a specific category of one of your input data. Now, based on the history of the temperature in LA, you can forecast the temperature of LA for year 2019. Finally, if you think the temperatures of the other cities can help you predict your output, you can add them as extra features, hence 6.